# Using Material theme on L preview

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

The L Developer Preview is currently on API level 20. However, apparently the themes require API level 21.

> `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar` requires API level 21

Is this a mistake, am I doing something wrong, or is it just not possible to use Material on the L Preview?

Comment: L developer preview is API level 21, Android 4.4W (wear) is level 20

Comment: @panini I am running the L on my Nexus 5, and Android Studio recognizes API 20. Also, SDK 21 is not available for download.

Comment: I think you need to set your AndroidManifest to <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="L" android:targetSdkVersion="L" />

Comment: sorry, thats "android-L", not just L. see this thread: http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2964nb/for_those_of_you_having_problems_building_with/

Comment: Ah something like that seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To elaborate on @panini's comments, I'm using this in my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionName buildVersion.version
    }

/* ... */
}
```

Placing the `styles.xml` in the `values-v21` folder, enables the theme to run on the L Preview.

Comment: In doc it is specified to use minSdkVersion 'L', but I haven't investigated about the reason.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti The minSdkVersion is set to 'L' automatically when building, to avoid releasing apps with preview features.