# Android Studio won't build with 'L' Version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to build my module with the new L dev release, but I'm getting an error

```
Failed to parse <uses-sdk minSdkVeresion='L'>:must be an integer number or codename.
```

this is in a auto generated Manifest.xml file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout this thread over at reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2964nb/for_those_of_you_having_problems_building_with/

Comment: Are you using the beta (0.8), or the last developer preview (0.6.1)?

Comment: duplicate (of sorts) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439958/using-material-theme-on-l-preview

Comment: Tanis, I am using 0.6.1, should I go with 0.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Android Studio to 0.8.0 and use the android-plugin 0.12.