# L preview: Call requires API level 21 (current min is 20)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying L and got an API level error. I have set the current min to 'L' but it seems Android Studio think it's 20.

How to fix it?

[image: error]

[image: gradle]

Comment: Check out that link: http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2964nb/for_those_of_you_having_problems_building_with  It says "If you're using Android Studio, in your build.gradle, have your "compileSdkVersion" and your "targetSdkVersion" both be "android-L", not 20 or "L" or 'L'." Maybe that helps

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439958/using-material-theme-on-l-preview

Comment: @CommonsWare I've checked the question. I think it's not quite the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Material theme on L preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439958/using-material-theme-on-l-preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I updated Android Studio 0.6.1 to 0.8.0** and the error disappeared.

**build.gradle looks exactly the same**:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.prt2121.tryl'
    minSdkVersion 'L'
    targetSdkVersion 'L'
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
```

I don't think my question is a duplicate but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
```

to

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion '21.0.2'
```

Note `android-L` is in single quotes but `21` isn't. `21` is an integer and not a string.

Comment: I have the problem with L-preview API 20 and the problem was solved. API 21 is Lollipop. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: i see. i think you then had to set targetSdkVersion="L" in AndroidManifest.xml file. glad your problem is solved.