# I want to use the android L theme

Tags: android, styles, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme

hello :) I want to change my app so it will have the Material theme, so .. I installed the new adt, updated all on sdk manager, and did this stuff:

I opened a new file - /res/values/styles.xml and used there this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <!-- your app's theme inherits from the Material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- theme customizations -->
  </style>
</resources>
```

And at the AndroidManifest I used this code:

```
        <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

at the styles.xml I get this error:

"error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'."

what do I need to change?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439958/using-material-theme-on-l-preview

Comment: @CommonsWare I can't fix it.. also, at startup I get console error :  [2014-06-28 23:59:22 - WhiteTAP] Unable to resolve target 'android-19'

Comment: `Unable to resolve target 'android-19'` means that you are specifying that you want to build something using the API Level 19 version of the Android SDK, but you have not downloaded that via the SDK Manager.

Comment: @CommonsWare ty, I will try to download :) I updated the adt and didn't know I need to download again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try following

1. Go to project->properties->Android
2. Check build target should be L (In case you are not seeing L in build target, please download it via SDK Manager)

   3. In your manifest.xml file please mentioned the minimumtarget sdk value as L.

It will solve your problem.[image]

Comment: thank you but I had a mistake, my phone running 4.4.2 so it will not work :(

Comment: @user3784668 You still can test it with emulators ;)

Comment: So we cannot build an App that is compatible to versions 4.0 to L? This should be possible as stated in the first paragraph of the compatibility section: https://developer.android.com/preview/material/compatibility.html

Comment: As a side note, on Android studio the settings are under
`Right Click Project in Project Explorer> Open Module Settings> Flavors`

Answer (score 0):

create a new emulator with api level 21 and change the minimum and maximum sdk versions to 21.